# An attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

This is my code

```
#(1) 
md1 <- ddply(model1_81[,4:84],~rownames(model1_81), summarize, missingData= mean(is.na(model1_81[,4:84])),2)

#(2) 
md1
  
#(3) 
md1 <- md1[order(md1$rownames(model1_81)),]
```

Note : (1) and (2) run well without any issues. Then when I run (3), it said `"Error in order(md1$rownames(model1_81)) : attempt to apply non-function"`.

I did not find out what was wrong with my code.
Please help me out with this.
Benny

Comment: do either of these work? `md1[order(rownames(md1)), ]` or `md1[order(md1$rownames), ]`

Comment: `ddply` should be returning a `data.frame`, so `mdl` is a frame. Using `summarize` (whether from `plyr::` or `dplyr::`), I highly doubt that any of the columns are functions, so `mdl$anything(..)` (using a column as a function) is a mistake. I agree with DaveArmstrong, and am suggesting we close this as a typo (and non-reproducible as well).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will get back to you while checking the update

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
#(1) 
md1 <- ddply(model1_81[,4:84],~rownames(model1_81), summarize, missingData= mean(is.na(model1_81[,4:84])),2)

#(2) 
md1

#(3) 
md1 <- md1[order(as.numeric(row.names(md1))),]
```